# want to read rows of data from excel to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, gridview, datatable, dataset

I want to read data from excel.

I have 18 Columns and number of rows may very from 150 to 500.

After reading the data i want to show it in grid view as well insert it into database same time.

I have a code, which can read only column wise, actually that is not my requirement.

I want row wise.

```
enter code here

For rCount = 4 To rCount
                objValues = CType(exCell(rCount, 1), Excel.Range).Value()
                If objValues <> Nothing Then
                    '  dtRecords.Columns.Add(objValues.ToString)
                    dtRecords.Rows.Add(objValues.ToString)
                    totalRecords += 1
                End If
                Exit For
            Next


            ds.Tables.Add(dtRecords)
            If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                grvRecords.AutoGenerateColumns = True
                grvRecords.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

            End If
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with SQL you can use ADO.NET for Retrieving data from Excel.
See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934/en

Comment: No, this was not  my requirement, I need to read rows from my excel and insert it to SQl server. While inserting i ll check whether those rows are existing or not, according to that a flag ll b return to the front end.